# Number of posets (equivalently: transitive DAGs) with labeled elements

Tags: co.combinatorics

It's hard to count the number of posets with a given number of elements; Sloane's [A001035](http://oeis.org/A001035) has it only up to 18.  Are asymptotic results known?

My actual interest is in transitive relations, Sloane's [A006905](http://oeis.org/A006905), but it's not hard to convert between these.  I would accept an answer giving either.

[1] Götz Pfeiffer, [Counting Transitive Relations](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL7/Pfeiffer/pfeiffer6.html), *Journal of Integer Sequences* **7** (2004).

[2] R. P. Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics, 1986.

Answer (score 2):

The asymptotics for acyclic graphs is not the same as for those that are *transitive*. The asymptotics for posets is given in D. J. Kleitman and B. L. Rothschild, *Trans. Amer.  Math. Soc.* **205** (1975), 205-220.

Comment: You're right, I misstated the problem.  My ultimate interest is the number of transitive relations on a relation with labeled elements, Pfeiffer's T(n).

Comment: If $f(n)$ is the number of $n$-element posets, or labelled posets, or transitive relations, or labelled transitive relations, etc., then
$f(n)= 2^{\frac{n^2}{4} + o(n^2)}$. If you want an asymptotic rather than logarithmically asymptotic formula, then the situation is more delicate and depends on the precise objects being enumerated. 

Answer (score 1):

If you look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph#Enumeration

And then look at the cited paper by our own contributor B. McKay et al, section 3 (the paper is freely available) they discuss asymptotics, and give references to papers by E. Bender et al (references 1, 2 in the paper). The paper (ref 4) by Gessel counts by number of sources and sinks, which is surely within $\epsilon$ of what you seek.

Comment: That does seem to answer the question I asked.  Unfortunately... what I actually wanted was A001035, not A003024.  Any ideas?